# How does this line of code work?

Tags: c++, c, memory, pointers

So I was recently looking at someone's code and I saw that the compiler didn't complain nor were there any run time errors with the following:

```
const char *p = "I didn't malloc...";
```

The code above works but I was wondering how. Here is what I think is happening. Can anyone confirm this please?

So "I didn't malloc..." gets allocated statically on the stack at compile time and the address to that is passed to the pointer p. Similar to how static array's are allocated. I am 90% sure of this, but some confirmation would help.

Thanks.

Comment: What compiler are you using? compliant compilers should reject this.

Comment: The type of `p` should be `char const *` since that segment of data ("normally") isn't writable, most compilers issues a warning these days.

Comment: @Dani No, they shouldn't. It's perfectly normal standard C and C++.

Comment: @cnicutar: string literals should be `const char *`, so this line should be an error of `assignment discards qualifiers`.

Comment: @Dani: No. In C++03 and before there is an auto conversion from `char const*` to `char*` (to allow for backwards comparability with C). I think this was deprecated in C++11. But most compiler will produce a warning.

Comment: @Edwin: Increase the warning level of your compiler and you will see it. (Note: most warnings are real logical errors in your code and should be fixed).

Comment: Editing the question to *add* the const qualifier has made it really confusing to read (with the current answers). Why did you do it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That's a string literal. The standard doesn't know about "stack", "heaps" etc - those are implementation details. So there's no "standard" location.

But **typically it's not on the stack**. It's in a read-only region called `text`. And it's not "*similar to how static array's are allocated*".

Comment: The region called `data` on Unix is not read-only.  These days, read-only data is usually in the `text` segment, isn't it?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler You're right of course. `data` is for writable initialized stuff.

Answer (score 8):

You have an string literal `"I didn't malloc..."` located somewhere in the read only memory(exactly where is Implementation defined) which is pointed to by the pointer `p`.

Important thing to note is any attempt to change this string literal will result in **Undefined Behavior**.

In fact in C++ it is deprecated to declare a string literal like you did.
So in C++ You should a `const` qualifier in place like:

```
const char *p = "I didn't malloc...";
```

Answer (score 5):

The memory is also allocated read-only any attempt to change *p is undefined.
Not generally on the stack though, it would be part of the data segment of the executable

Answer (score 2):

The string literal `"I didn't malloc..."` is stored in a read-only area of the data segment and `p` contains the address of that location.

Answer (score 2):

p will point to a read-only area of memory which will be allocated on the stack.
Moreover the compiler will automatically null-terminate the string adding a '\0' byte at the end.

Not using const is dangerous, in fact the g++ compiler issue an warning for the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, const char *argv[])
{
    char *p = "AString8";
    printf("%s\n", p);
    printf("Last char: %c hex: %x\n", p[7], p[7]);
    printf("Last char + 1: %c hex: %x\n", p[8], p[8]);
    return 0;
}
```

warning: deprecated conversion from string constant to ‘char*’

Program output:

```
Last char: 8 hex: 38

Last char + 1:  hex: 0
```